# Initialize a constant that is a dynamic array of fixed arrays?

Tags: delphi

Can I initialize a constant *dynamic* array of arrays?

If:

```
type
  tNamePair = array[1..2] of String;
  tPairList = array of tNamePair;
```

How can I create an initialized constant? I can't get the code below compile:

```
const
  PairList: tPairList = ( ('One', '1'), 
                          ('Two', '2'),
                          ('Three', '3'));
```

If that's not possible, can a constant *fixed* array be initialized with a *fixed* array:

```
 type
    tPairList: array[1..3] of tNamePair;
```

If that's not possible, can a constant *dynamic* array be initialized with a *record*:

```
tNamePair = record 
              English: String;
              Number: String;
            end;           
tPairList = array of tNamePair;
```

if that's not possible can a constant *fixed* array be initialized with a *record*:

```
tNamePair = record 
              English: String;
              Number: String;
            end;           
tPairList = array[1..3] of tNamePair;
```

If that's not possible, any suggestions other than just hardwiring assignments in the code, which frankly would have taken me less time than composing this question!

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/247672/62576) to a somewhat similar question useful. Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2481559/62576).

Comment: As the compiler cannot know the length of a *dynamic* array, I guess it is impossible initialize one.

Comment: _constant dynamic_ is a nice oxymoron. :-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Prior to XE7 you could not create *dynamic* array constants.  Constants have to be known at compile time, but *dynamic* arrays are allocated at runtime.

A *fixed* array of *fixed* arrays can be declared at compile-time:

```
type
  tNamePair = array[1..2] of String;
  tPairList = array[1..3] of tNamePair;

const
  PairList: tPairList = ( ('One', '1'),
                          ('Two', '2'),
                          ('Three', '3'));
```

A *fixed* array of *records* can also be declared at compile-time:

```
type
  tNamePair = record
              English: String;
              Number: String;
            end;
  tPairList = array[1..3] of tNamePair;

const
  PairList: tPairList = ( (English: 'One'; Number: '1'),
                          (English: 'Two'; Number: '2'),
                          (English: 'Three'; Number: '3'));
```

If you need a *dynamic* array, you have to construct it at run-time.  You can either build it up directly:

```
type
  tNamePair = array[1..2] of String;
  tPairList = array of tNamePair;

var
  PairList: tPairList;

initialization
  SetLength(PairList, 3);
  PairList[0][1] := 'One';
  PairList[0][2] := '1';
  PairList[1][1] := 'Two';
  PairList[1][2] := '2';
  PairList[2][1] := 'Three';
  PairList[2][2] := '3';
end.
```

Or you can define a compile-time constant *fixed* array and copy it into the *dynamic* array at run-time:

```
type
  tNamePair = array[1..2] of String;
  tPairList = array[1..3] of tNamePair;
  tPairListDyn = array of tNamePair;

const
  PairList: tPairList = ( ('One', '1'),
                          ('Two', '2'),
                          ('Three', '3'));

function MakePairListDyn(const Pairs: tPairList): tPairListDyn;
var
  I, J: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Pairs));
  J := 0;
  for I := Low(Pairs) to High(Pairs) do begin
    Result[J] := Pairs[I];
    Inc(J);
  end;
end;

var
  Pairs: tPairListDyn;

initialization
  Pairs := MakePairListDyn(PairList);
end.
```

For the situation post XE7 see [@LURD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25622740/65863).

Comment: thanks for reminding me to the somewhat unusual syntax of declaring const arrays of records, which I will immediately forget again ;-)

Comment: Thank you, Remy, for taking the time to create such a useful response.

Comment: You should initialize variable J before the for loop if you don't want some AVs here and there ;)

Answer (score 14):

In XE7 it is possible to declare dynamic array constants.

Simple case:

```
const
  a: TArray<String> = ['Delphi','XE7'];
```

In your example this compiles:

```
type
  tNamePair = TArray<String>;
  tPairList = TArray<tNamePair>;

const
  PairList: tPairList = [['One', '1'],['Two', '2'],['Three', '3']];
```

---

To create a dynamic array of a record, it can be done at runtime like this:

```
Type
  TNamePair = record
    English: String;
    Number: String;
    class function Define(_English,_Number: String): TNamePair; static;
  end;
  TPairList = TArray<TNamePair>;

class function TNamePair.Define(_English, _Number: String): TNamePair;
begin
  Result.English := _English;
  Result.Number := _Number;
end;

var
  pl : TPairList;
begin
  pl := [TNamePair.Define('A','1'),TNamePair.Define('B','2')];
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Wow!  I was just wondering about what was new in XE7.  You've got a good memory to have found this two year old thread! THANKS.

Comment: Not so much my memory, but a certain search engine (read Google) was helpful :)

Comment: @LURD Do you know of a way to use a dynamic array constant with the OP's original definition of TNamePair (a record)?

Comment: @Graymatter, no not a constant, but at runtime you can do as in my updated answer.

Comment: @LURD Thanks, that's quite cool. I tested something similar with a static class function and the `Create(...)` syntax that can be used in a const but got the same error that I did when trying to use a const record format. Ordinal value expected or something like that.

Comment: IMHO this `TNamePair.Define` is just an ugly awful boilerplate. I end updeclaring ad hoc INLINE functions to create record instances.`function r(const c: cardinal; m: string): rErrorDecription; inline;
begin
  Result.Code := c;
  Result.Message := m;
end;  
  XMLLiteErrorMessages := TXMLLiteKnownErrors.Create(

    r($C00CEE01, 'unexpected end of input'),
    r($C00CEE02, 'unrecognized encoding'),
    r($C00CEE03, 'unable to switch the encoding'),....`

Comment: @Arioch'The how is this different from LU RD's `TNamePair.Define` approach?

Comment: @Bozzy `inline` provides to a _sufficiently smart compiler_ a hint, that this can be calculated in compilation time (i do not think Delphi Classic would actually ever do it, though) rather than runtime, and more importantly for me, less **boilerplate**, much better signal to noise ratio. Also notice that in my XE2 `dynamic array constants` are not part of the language, thus using `arraytype.Create` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method :

```
const
  C_ARRAY_CODE : array ['a'..'d'] of string = ('01','02','03','04');
var Conter:Char;
begin
  //Use With Loop
  for Conter := Low(C_ARRAY_CODE) to high(C_ARRAY_CODE) do
    ShowMessage(C_ARRAY_CODE[Conter]);

  //Use Direct
  ShowMessage(C_ARRAY_CODE['a']);
end;
```